# How to upload a file in a directory containing the record ID on Symfony

Tags: php, file-upload, symfony1

I have a file upload form in the frontend.

At the moment, when a new record is created, the file is uploaded to

```
%sf_data_dir%/files/
```

but due to some business logic I need the file to be uploaded to

```
%sf_data_dir%/files/%record_id%/
```

Therefore the uploaded file should be saved AFTER the record is created.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use file upload, your form certainly make use of the sfValidatorFile (if not, that's wrong):

```
$this->validatorSchema['image'] = new sfValidatorFile(array(
                                    'required' => true,
                                    'mime_types' => 'web_images',
                           ));
```

This validator return a sfValidatedFile instance that can be saved anywhere you want (it's safer than move_uploaded_file, there is checks on the directory, filename...).

In your action (or in the form, as you want/need), you can now do this:

```
protected function processForm(sfWebRequest $request, sfForm $form)
{
  $form->bind(
    $request->getParameter($form->getName()),
    $request->getFiles($form->getName())
  );

  if ($form->isValid())
  {
    $job = $form->save();
    // Saving the file to filesystem
    $file = $form->getValue('my_upload_field');
    $file->save('/path/to/save/'.$job->getId().'/myimage.'.$file->getExtension());
    $this->redirect('job_show', $job);
  }
}
```

Don't hesitate to open sfValidatedFile to see how it work.

Comment: Thank you! I've came out with a different solution, but your one looks much more elegant.
As soon as I test it I'll accept your answer!